Defining polynomial for a compositum of splitting fields
Let $L_1,...,L_n/K$ be finite separable field extensions. Then the compositum extension $L:=L_1\cdot ...\cdot L_n/K$ is also finite and separable. Thus by the primitive element theorem, there are $\theta_i$ and $\theta$ in some fixed algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$ such that $L_i=K(\theta_i)$ and $L=K(\theta)$.
Suppose the $f_i(x)$ are the minimal polynomials of the $\theta_i$ over $K$, so that $L_i\cong K[x]/\langle f_i(x)\rangle$. Assuming that the $f_i$ are known, is there an algorithm to compute a generating polynomial for $L/K$, i.e. an irreducible polynomial $f\in K[x]$ so that $L=L_1\cdot...\cdot L_n\cong K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$, and $f$ can be computed from the $f_i$ in some way?
After some searching, I think the answer is related to the resultant
$$\operatorname{Res}_y(f_i(y),f_j(x-y)),$$
which is mentioned in section 2 of [1] and section 3.2 of [2]; [1] states that the above resultant does the trick when $n=2$ (albeit without a formal proof), while [2] explains that the resultant has roots which are precisely the sums of a root of $f_i$ and a root of $f_j$ (not hard to see), but I don't see when we get irreducibility.

[1] Awtrey, C., Cesarski, T., & Jakes, P. (2017). Determining Galois Groups of Reducible Polynomials Via Discriminants and Linear Resolvents. JP Journal of Algebra, Number Theory and Applications, 39(5), 685–702.
[2] Soicher, L. (1981). The Computation of Galois Groups [Master’s Thesis, Concordia University]. https://spectrum.library.concordia.ca/id/eprint/4916/1/MK49693.pdf

The resultant need not be irreducible. Let, for example, $f(x)=x^4-10x^2+1$, $g(x)=x^4-14x^2+9$ be the minimal polynomials of $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt2+\sqrt5$ respectively. Then the resultant $\mathrm{res}_x(f(x),g(t-x))$ factors as $(t^4-16t^2+4)^2(t^8-64t^6+904t^4-3840t^2+3600)$.

If the resultant is separable, it should be irreducible precisely when $L_i \cap L_j = K$. This follows from a general result about composita of field extensions (e.g., Proposition 21 in Section 13.2 of Dummit and Foote). If the resultant is not separable, take $f_i$ (or $f_j$) and perform a Tschirnhaus transformation on it (see for example Section 6.3 in Cohen's book A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory) to obtain another minimal polynomial $\tilde{f_i}$ for $L_i$. Then compute the resultant again but with $\tilde{f_i}$ and $f_j$; I'll simply write this as $\text{Res}(\tilde{f_i},f_j)$. You can double-check the source code, but I'm guessing this is essentially how the "polcompositum" function works in Pari/GP. If the separable resultant is reducible, pick an irreducible factor of largest degree (there could be several) and that will define the compositum. You can easily extend this to composita of more than two fields by iterating the resultant computation. For example, $\text{Res}(\text{Res}(f_i,f_j),f_k)$ will give you a polynomial defining $L_iL_jL_k$, as long as each resultant is separable and you pick the largest irreducible factor of each resultant.
